# How to redirect domain:port to domain with Glassfish?

Tags: eclipse, http, https, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have a domain like `www.example.com`, I'm using `Glassfish`, which hosts my application at port `12544`.

So I wonder two things :

1. How can I redirect this `www.example.com:12544` to `www.example.com` ?
2. And the same way but for `https` ? I mean, `https://www.example.com` ?

I am really new to `Glassfish` any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to place *Glassfish* behind *Apache http server* and configure apache to point requests to glassfish. Therefore http requests are handled by Apache and all `www.example.com` requests are pointed to `www.example.com:12544` internally. Below is a brief explanation of how to do this.

- Install Glassfish 3+ (make sure your listener is created and activated on **8009** and your `jk` is enabled)
- Install [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) (2.2+)
- get the [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/) connector and place it into *apache modules folder* to do the configurations.
- create a `worker.properties` file and place it into *apache conf folder*. It should contain the following properties:

```
    worker.list=worker1
    worker.worker1.type=ajp13
    worker.worker1.host=localhost
    worker.worker1.port=8009
```

- Open `httpd.conf` file in *apache conf folder*  and place the following commands (**outside Virtual Host**):

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
#location of the worker file
JkWorkersFile conf/worker.properties
#where to put jk logs
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
#log level [deug/error/info]
JkLogLevel debug
#Log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"
# Indicate to send SSL KEY SIZE
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
# Set the request format
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
# Send all jsp requests to Glassfish
JkMount /*.jsp worker1
# Send all webapp requests to Glassfish
JkMount /* worker1
```

You need also to add a **VirtualHost** section in your conf file. This maps your domain with the path in Glassfish so Apache will be able to see it. The following tells apache to map all /myapp/* links to glassfish

```
<VirtualHost 111.111.111.111:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain
    ServerName domain
    JkMount /myapp/* worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: if your Glassfish listener is not created you can created from cmd using glassfish asadmin with the following command:

```
asadmin create-network-listener --protocol http-listener-1 --listenerport 8009 --jkenabled true jk-connector
```

- Restart Apache and Glassfish for the new configurations to be updated. Apache should now see your Glassfish on port 80. So your `www.example.com:12544` will be served on `www.example.com`.